# Как исправить горизонтальный скролл в HTML?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Хотел сделать переключатель в html.Не понимаю почему появляется такой скролл Вот код:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Âåá-ñòðàíè÷êà</title>
        <style>
            * {
                transition: 500ms;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            body {
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                background-color: #d8dbdf7d;
            }
            
            .header {
                background-color: #F21D44;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 23px;                
            }
            
            .header .menu {
                padding: 16px 12px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                color: white;
            }

            .header .menu:hover {
                padding: 16px 12px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                color: white;
                background-color: #FF2626;
            }
            
            .banner {
                background-size: 1300px 600px;
                background-image: url(https://auth.services.adobe.com/img/canvas/Fotolia_158229208_XL.jpg);
                padding: 60px 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 60px;
            }
            
            .banner h4 {
                font-size: 55px;
            }

            .welcome {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 280px;
            }

            .sub {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 430px;   
            }
            
            .banner .fs {
                font-size: 50px;
                border: 3.5px solid blue;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                margin: 5px auto;
                width: 270px;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }

            .banner .fs:hover {
                font-size: 50px;
                border: 3.5px solid blue;
                background-color: blue;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                margin: 5px auto;
                width: 270px;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }
            
            .banner .is {
                font-size: 50px;
                border: 3.5px solid yellow;
                color: white;
                border-radius: 15px;
                margin: 5px auto;
                width: 270px;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }

            .banner .is:hover {
                font-size: 50px;
                border: 3.5px solid yellow;
                background-color: yellow;
                color: black;
                border-radius: 15px;
                margin: 5px auto;
                width: 270px;
                padding: 0 20px;
            }

            #table {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
            
            table {
                width: 100%;
                height: 300px;
                font-size: 25px;
            }
            
            #section {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            .checkbox {
                width: 45px;
                display: block;
                float: right;
                padding: 8px 20px;
            }

            .logo {
                width: 50px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                padding: 4px 15px; 
            }

            input[type="checkbox"]
            {
                position: relative;
                width: 60px;
                height: 30px;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                background: #c6c6c6;
                outline: none;
                border-radius: 20px;
                transition: 0.5s;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            }

            input:checked[type="checkbox"]
            {
                background: #03a9f4;
            }

            input[type="checkbox"]:before
            {
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background: #fff;
                transform: scale(1.1);
                box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                transition: 0.5s;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#logo"><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Professionelle_reinigung_%28F%29.svg/2048px-Professionelle_reinigung_%28F%29.svg.png"></a>
            <a href="#home"><div class="menu">###</div></a>
            <a href="#logos"><div class="menu">###</div></a>
            <a href="#illustrations"><div class="menu">###</div></a>
            <a href=#web-sites><div class="menu">###</div></a>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="banner">
            <h4>
                <div class="welcome">###</div>
                <div class="sub">###</div>
                <a href="#facebook"><div class="fs">###</div></a>
                <a href="#instagram"><div class="is">###</div></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
            <p id="section">Table</p>
            <table border="1" bordercolor="#826FFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                    </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                    <td>###</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p id="section">###</p>
            <div class="fgames">
            </div>
            <a href="#home"><h3 id="more">###</h3></a>
            <p class="footer">###</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Каким браузером пользуетесь?

Comment: браузер Google Chrome

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, достаточно кода, для воспроизведения ошибки

Comment: все добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте

```
.checkbox input {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам исправилось!!!